# Unit test for function which returns function

Tags: unit-testing, go

How to write unit test for the function getAreaFunc() in vs code. Code coverage does not cover the returned function. Can anyone provide a example ?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    areaF := getAreaFunc()
    res := areaF(2, 4)
    fmt.Println(res)
}

func getAreaFunc() func(int, int) int {
    return func(x, y int) int {
        return x * y
    }
}
```

Comment: Call getAreaFunction and _evaluate_ the returned function (multiple times) to validate it does the right computation.

Answer (score 2):

> Code coverage does not cover the returned function

I'm not sure how you implement the unit test, but the returned function of `getAreaFunc` definitely can be covered by a unit test.

For example:

```golang
// main.go

package main

func getAreaFunc() func(int, int) int {
    return func(x, y int) int {
        return x * y
    }
}
```

```golang
// main_test.go

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func TestGetAreaFunc(t *testing.T) {
    areaF := getAreaFunc()
    res := areaF(2, 4)
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Once you execute command `go test -cover .` you will get `100%` coverage in result